# Inserting document ID into WhereCondition of Nested Repeater

Tags: c#, repeater, kentico

I have a nested repeater being used as a left nav. On the secondary page, I want it to show only the tertiary items of the current secondary page. None of the tertiary items of other secondary items should show on this repeater. The problem I am having is that I currently have it where all the tertiary items are showing, since it can only retrieve information in the context of the first (parent) repeater.

I feel like I should be able to call the document ID of the current page and insert it into the transformation of the second (child) repeater, but again, it can only retrieve document ID and Node ID from its parent repeater item only.

Would you be able to help me find a custom function or code to help me figure out this problem? Thanks!

Comment: So basically you want the menu to show pages underneath the current one? Also can you post some of the code you're using, both the transformation and the control.

Answer (score 0):

you are able to access document id of current document. Following code will print it out:

```
<%=CMSContext.CurrentDocument.DocumentID.ToString() %>
```

So you can similarly use the document id in some transformation method:

```
<%#SomeMethod(CMSContext.CurrentDocument.DocumentID, otherParameter, ...) %>
```